nesting of units within siunitx
Isn't it allowed to nest units in siunitx v3.2.2 anymore? The following snippet worked fine with 2.7g.
\SI{-160}{\dBmWperHertz}

with the macro
 \DeclareSIUnit{\dBmWperHertz}{\dB(\SI{1}{\mW\per\hertz})}

Now it results in a mere
\dB ->\ERROR


Can you provide a complete example? And copy-paste the error text?

Yes, but only Thursday, alas.

Sorry, but I don't follow. do you mean you can only provide an example on Thursday? If you have access to the internet, why can't you provide an example now? It's just a question of completing your snippet so it compiles to produce the error and then pasting the error into the question. Not that it's a problem if you wait until Thursday, as far as SE is concerned. But if you don't want to wait, use Overleaf if you don't have access to a local tex and are in a hurry. Or https://texlive.net/run.
